# App won't run on iOS 4.2, Architecture issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3, xcodebuild, armv6

I have an app that I developed in Xcode 4.3.2. I am using the base SDK as 5.1. The app installs fine in iOS 5.0 and above. But I need to support iOS 4.0 and above.

The compiler I am using is Apple LLVM compiler 3.1.

I have added both armv6 and armv7 to the architectures (See attached image)[image])

I created an AdHoc build. When I sync it using iTunes, it syncs fine with iOS 5.0 and above, I have not tested in iOS 4.3, but it does not install in iOS 4.2.1. It gives this error:

The app "App Name" could not be installed on the iPod "iPod Name" because it is not compatible with this iPod.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you remove the `armv7` from the `Required device capabilities` in the `info.plist`

Comment: Is the Deployment Target set to 4.2?

Comment: @NSArray: Yes, Deployment Target is set to 4.2

Comment: @rckones: I will have to check that. Will check now.

Comment: @rckoenes: Yes that worked. You might want to add this as an answer, I can accept this and probably people could benefit from this. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `armv7` from the `Required device capabilities` in the `info.plist`.

This restricts the app being installed on device that do not have an ARMV7 processor, like older iPad touches and iPhones.